# Pandas - split text with values in parenthesis into multiple columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe column with values as below:

```
HexNAc(6)Hex(7)Fuc(1)NeuAc(3)
HexNAc(6)Hex(7)Fuc(1)NeuAc(3)
HexNAc(5)Hex(4)NeuAc(1)
HexNAc(6)Hex(7)
```

I want to split this information into multiple columns:

```
HexNAc Hex Fuc NeuAc
6      7   1   3
6      7   1   3
5      4   0   1
6      7   0   0
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done with a combination of string splits and `explode` (`pandas` version >= 0.25) then `pivot`. The rest cleans up some of the columns and fills missing values.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['HexNAc(6)Hex(7)Fuc(1)NeuAc(3)', 'HexNAc(6)Hex(7)Fuc(1)NeuAc(3)',
               'HexNAc(5)Hex(4)NeuAc(1)', 'HexNAc(6)Hex(7)'])

(pd.DataFrame(s.str.split(')').explode().str.split('\(', expand=True))
   .pivot(columns=0, values=1)
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
   .dropna(how='all', axis=1)
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))
```

---

```
  Fuc Hex HexNAc NeuAc
0   1   7      6     3
1   1   7      6     3
2   0   4      5     1
3   0   7      6     0
```

Comment: i was also taking the same approach :) you beat me there : `(df['col'].str.split(')').explode().str.split('\(',expand=True).dropna()
  .set_index(0,append=True).unstack(fill_value=0))`

Comment: Thank you ALollz and @anky_91 - this solution makes sense to me but when I try it, I get the following error:                                                              
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'                                             Any ideas why?

Comment: @kkhatri99 try an update the pandas version to version `.25.0` , you can check the present version using `pd.__version__`

Comment: @anky_91 find a alternative :-)

Answer (score 4):

Check

```
pd.DataFrame(s.str.findall('\w+').map(lambda x : dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))).tolist())
Out[207]: 
   Fuc Hex HexNAc NeuAc
0    1   7      6     3
1    1   7      6     3
2  NaN   4      5     1
3  NaN   7      6   NaN
```

Comment: Super cool way to do this! (Though could get tricky with decimal values :d)